# How to remove duplicate values while they are being read?

Tags: c++, stdset

MRE (because license issues):

```cpp
std::set<std::string> pool;

// values: 10 10 1 3 4 3 3 2 5 7 5 4 3 9 8 8 7
// (values is an iterable collection)
for (const auto& value : values) {
    pool.insert(value);
}

// expected read: 10 1 3 4 2 5 7 9 8

// actual read: 1 10 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 (10 after 1 because std::string)
```

what collection do I use to achieve this?

Comment: cannot store the values and then call std::unique because the file being read already crosses over 30GB

Comment: `std::set` is an ordered container

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I am using it to leverage its property of removing duplicates on the fly. Is there any other container which will allow me to do this and preserve the order?

Comment: Use 2 containers. Read into the set, using the return value of `insert` to work out if this item was new. Then add only new items to a vector. That vector will be the unique items in insertion order.

Comment: @MikeVine, that seems like a perfectly good idea, but it still looks pretty RAM intensive. Even now, the RAM usage is surpassing 90%.

Comment: You can always write them to a file rather than a vector. Then release your `std::set` and load the file into a vector.

Comment: @Galik this sounds perfectly fine! Will try this out.

Comment: What are the bounds of the input values? Do you expect them to small or arbitrary 64-bit values?

Comment: @bitmask the values will be `std::string` objects...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use 2 containers. Read into the set, using the return value of insert to work out if this item was new. Then add only new items to a vector. That vector will be the unique items in insertion order.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::set<std::string>::iterator> itemsInOrder;
    std::set<std::string> pool;

    std::vector<std::string> values = {"10", "10", "1", "3"};

    for (const auto& value : values)
    {
        auto ret = pool.insert(value);
        if (ret.second)
        {
            itemsInOrder.push_back(ret.first);
        }
    }

    for (auto item : itemsInOrder)
    {
        std::cout << *item << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make this a bit prettier with structured bindings: `auto [it, success] = pool.insert(value)`.

Comment: I would use: `std::unordered_set<std::string_view>`: https://godbolt.org/z/1nbPKdszG of course you have to remember about object lifetime (like in case where you used iterators).

Answer (score 0):

"pool.insert" return a pair,  pair.second is the bool type which was inserted a element or not

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    set<int> pool;
    pair<set<int>::iterator, bool> k;
    vector<int> v={10, 10, 1, 3, 6, 3, 3, 2, 5, 7, 5, 6, 3, 9, 8, 8, 7};
    vector<int> result;
    // values: 10 10 1 3 6 3 3 2 5 7 5 6 3 9 8 8 7
    // (values is an iterable collection)
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        k = pool.insert(v[i]);
        if(k.second==true) {
            result.push_back(v[i]);
        }
    }
    // expected read: 10 1 3 6 2 5 7 9 8
    // actual read: 10 1 3 6 2 5 7 9 8
    int i = 0;
    return 0;
}
```